# How to change data type number to autonumber where the table already contains data

Tags: ms-access

One of my team mates accidentally put `Number` instead of `autonumber` for one column and populated the table with 5000 records. How do I change it to `autonumber` when the table is already populated?

Comment: Add a new column for the autonumber.

Comment: If I create new column how can I get the data into that? I already have data into the column where i have to change number to autonumber. Same problem in another table. There it is saying I have to change relationships of that particular column in relationship window. I saw that but donno how to change relationship of that column. Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to do this, as far as I know, is to create a new table with identical fields (except with the autonumber field instead of the number field), and then port all of the data in with a query.

From there, go through and modify any existing queries, code, or forms that refer to the old table and point them to the new table.

I've been through this with MS Access... it's not hard, but is a pain in the butt.

Comment: You can just rename the old table and then name the new table as the old table. No problem.